# web url returns json data then print via jquery

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have an url that prints

[{"outlet_group_id": "29","outlet_group_name": "Parco","outlet_group_code": "0000010"}]

and I have this code

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

  $.getJSON('http://sampl.elinkurl.com/services/accounts/id/3/date/20130102_20130108', 
    function(data) {
      var table='<table>';
      $.each( data, function( index, item){
      table+='<tr><td>'+item.outlet_group_id+'</td><td>'+item.outlet_group_name+'
      </td></tr>';       
    });
    table+='</table>';
    $("#content").html( table );        
    });
  });
</script>

<div id="content">
</div>
```

but it doesnt show

Comment: this is because your `item` doesnt have `outlet_group_id` and `outlet_group_name`

Comment: console.log(data); check what it prints.

Comment: sorry i pasted the wrng json file. its fixed alr

Answer (score 0):

the json format that will make your function work should be something like this:

```
[ {"outlet_group_name":"CHERRY ANTIPOLO","outlet_group_id":"260.83"},
  {"outlet_group_name":"CHERRY CONGRESSIONAL","outlet_group_id":"362.87"},
  {"outlet_group_name":"Cherry Shaw","outlet_group_id":"0"}
]
```

so, you either change the json, or change the jquery to match the correct names